# Running Python within PHP works within the CLI but not the XAMPP server

Tags: python, php, xampp

I have this Python script to use within a PHP page, and I have found out the code for PHP to run it. This is my code:

```
<?php
    $command = '3.8/bin/python3 googleNewsScraper.py CNN';
    $output = exec($command, $output, $status);
    echo $status;
    echo $output;
?>
```

When I use the command `php index.php`, it works fine and echos out the output of the command, which is good. But, it doesn't output anything on my XAMPP local server, so I echo'ed the status. When I use the full path to the python interpreter, it gives me 127, which is because it doesn't know that command. But, with the current command as shown above, I get a status of 2. I have tried using the full path to each file, tried using a simple file that can't return errors, tried editing `httpd.conf` to include `AddHandler cgi-script .py`, restarted XAMPP multiple times, but nothing is happening or working.

Just to be clear, I am 100% sure that this is not a problem with paths as I was able to print out the contents of the file using the exact same path (just used the command `echo file_get_contents("googleNewsScraper.py");`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I checked the error log and this is the error that is occurring:

```
[Mon Jun 29 05:44:17.177250 2020] [core:notice] [pid 652] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'

sh: 1: 3.8/bin/python3: Exec format error
```

EDIT 2: If I use the full path I get this error:

```
sh: 1: /Users/rosen59250/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/PHP API Page/3.8/bin/python3: not found
```

Comment: maybe use `/full/path/python3` and check log again. Server may run code in different folder then you expect and path can makes problem.

Comment: @furas nope. tried that including escaping all spaces, but that makes it worse. it says file not found.

Comment: do you get EXACTLY the same message in log ? If it is different then show it in question.

Comment: @furas added the error.

Comment: don't use spaces in path

Comment: @furas I escape the error by doing this: `/Users/rosen59250/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/PHP\ API\ Page/3.8/bin/python3` because that does it correctly. If I don't escape them, it gives another different error that says it isn't a valid path or something like that.